# Can't get my Ranges set up from my spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My overall goal here is to grab the values and row indices of three different columns on the original spreadsheet, evaluate them, and then save them to a new spreadsheet. I am wanted to accomplish this by using a macro initiated by a button on the original spreadsheet.

The plan to accomplish this was to

- create a Range for each column
- Loop through the most significant Range to grab and evaluate the each cell      value
- perform nested loops within the first loop to further evaluate the other two Ranges and grab their values
- assign values to variables
- create the new spreadsheet from a template
- write the values to the respective columns
- save the new spreadsheet

When I run the code below I get the error listed below. I'm confused because I thought this is how you reference an entire column:

[image]

```
Sub Transfer2NewWorkbook()
  Dim currentsheet As String
  Dim newsheet As String
  Dim analysisDate As String
  Dim initial As String
  Dim aInitial() As String
  Dim analystInit As String
  Dim batchNo As String

  Dim wb As Object
  Dim dataRangeA As Range, dataRangeB As Range, dataRangeI As Range
  Set dataA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


  ' Grab and Create filenames
  currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  newsheet = currentsheet & "-" & "uploadable"

  ' Grab data from original spreadsheet
  analysisDate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 9).Value

  initial = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value
  aInitial = Split(initial, "/")
  analystInit = aInitial(1)

  Set dataRangeA = Range("A4:A").Select ' <-- Line causing error
  Set dataRangeB = Range("B4:B").Select
  Set dataRangeI = Range("I4:I").Select

  For i = 1 To dataRangeA.Rows.Count
    dataA.Add Key:=i, Item:=dataRangeA.Cells.Value
  Next i

  Set wb = Workbooks.Add("C:\Users\dalythe\documents\uploadtemp.xlsx")

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 2).Value = analysisDate
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 4).Value = analystInit


  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (newsheet & ".xlsx")


End Sub
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.  (I will downvote you if the picture is still in the question next time I look at it.)  And you reference a range by, for instance, saying `Set myvariable = ` and then placing a `Range` object to the right of the `=`.  The `Range.Select` method does not return a `Range` object.  And you can't use "A4:A" as a range address.  So you need something like `Set dataRangeA = Range("A:A")`

Comment: The other advantage (besides avoiding downvotes) of placing code, and not just pictures of code, into the question is that people can help you fix the other mistakes without having to retype your whole code from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Set dataRangeA = Range("A:A").Select
Set dataRangeB = Range("B:B").Select
Set dataRangeI = Range("I:I").Select

For i = 4 To dataRangeA.Rows.Count
    dataA.Add Key:=i, Item:=dataRangeA.Cells.Value
Next i
```

Comment: Your response makes logical sense, but when I make that change I then get an "Object Required" Runtime error in the same location. Which I don't understand that because I declared the Ranges above.

Comment: You still need to put a `Range` object as the RHS in your `Set` statement

Answer (score 0):

After removing the .Select, my ranges were accepted.

```
Set dataRangeA = Range("A:A")
Set dataRangeB = Range("B:B")
Set dataRangeI = Range("I:I")

For i = 4 To dataRangeA.Rows.Count
   dataA.Add Key:=i, Item:=dataRangeA.Cells.Value
Next i
```

Thanks for the input **YowE3k**. Now I have to think on how I want my loop to end. Because doing it the way I have it above will cause it to run out of memory. The spreadsheet will not have a "predefined" number of rows. I guess I will have to have the user type "End" in the cell of the last row or something.

Comment: Which is why I said to include your code into the question - I would have posted an answer fixing that for you as well if I wasn't forced to retype your entire code to do so.  (And if you included enough code so that we could see what you were doing with the Dictionary. we may have been able to avoid your loop as well.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your response about the code. I will fix it now.

Comment: Thanks for the "posting" help. Got to learn how to post properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems with the particular line throwing the error are caused by two things:

1. `"A4:A"` is not a valid address in Excel.  You can either use `"A:A"` for the entire column or define the end of the range, e.g. `"A4:A272"`.
2. The `Range.Select` method does not return an object, so `Set dataRangeA = Range("A4:A").Select` is effectively `Set dataRangeA =`.

To fix your specific error, you could do something like:

```
Set dataRangeA = Range("A4", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

---

However, using unqualified `Cells` and `Range` and `Rows` is a dangerous habit to get into once you have more than one worksheet / workbook being used in your code, because those objects default to referring to the `ActiveSheet` in the `ActiveWorkbook` and that may not be the one you are expecting it to be.

The code below ensures that each object is qualified, plus makes some other improvements to your code (such as the inevitable out-of-memory error that would arise in populating the Dictionary).

```
Sub Transfer2NewWorkbook()
  Dim currentsheet As String
  Dim newsheet As String
  Dim analysisDate As String
  Dim initial As String
  Dim aInitial() As String
  Dim analystInit As String
  Dim batchNo As String

  Dim wb As Object
  Dim dataRangeA As Range, dataRangeB As Range, dataRangeI As Range
  Dim dataA As Object ' declare this, unless you have declared it at a higher
                      ' level scope

  Set dataA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  ' Grab and Create filenames
  currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  newsheet = currentsheet & "-" & "uploadable"

  'Use a With block to avoid having to constantly refer
  ' to "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)"
  With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    ' Grab data from original spreadsheet
    analysisDate = .Cells(1, 9).Value

    initial = .Cells(1, 2).Value
    aInitial = Split(initial, "/")
    analystInit = aInitial(1)

    Set dataRangeA = .Range("A4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set dataRangeB = .Range("B4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    Set dataRangeI = .Range("I4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))

    'This loop is making every entry in the Dictionary contain the value of 
    'every cell in the range - i.e. each of the 1048573 entries in the Dictionary
    'would have contained an array which was dimensioned As (1 To 1048573, 1 To 1)
    'For i = 1 To dataRangeA.Rows.Count
    '  dataA.Add Key:=i, Item:=dataRangeA.Cells.Value
    'Next i
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel in dataRangeA
      dataA.Add Key:=cel.Row, Item:=cel.Value
      'or 
      'dataA.Add Key:=cel.Row - 3, Item:=cel.Value
      'if you wanted A4's value to have a key of 1
    Next

    'Note: If you just wanted an array of values, you could have used
    '  Dim dataA As Variant
    '  dataA = Application.Transpose(.Range("A4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
    'and then access each value using dataA(1) for the value from A4,
    'dataA(2) for the value from A5, etc.
    'This then gets rid of the need for dataRangeA, and the need for a
    ' dictionary object, and the need for the loop populating the dictionary.
  End With

  Set wb = Workbooks.Add("C:\Users\dalythe\documents\uploadtemp.xlsx")
  With wb.Worksheets(1)

    .Cells(3, 2).Value = analysisDate
    .Cells(3, 4).Value = analystInit

  End With
  wb.SaveAs newsheet & ".xlsx"


End Sub
```